# Can the inverse Laplace transformation of these functions be found by using the residue theorem?

Tags: residue-calculus, inverse-laplace

While solving a partial differential equation, I came across the following four functions:

$$ F_1(s) = e^{  k \sqrt{ q^2 + cs^2 } } \tag 1$$
$$ F_2(s) = e^{ -k \sqrt{ q^2 + cs^2 } } \tag 2$$
$$ F_3(s) = e^{  k \sqrt{ q^2 - cs^2 } } \tag 3$$
$$ F_4(s) = e^{ -k \sqrt{ q^2 - cs^2 } } \tag 4$$

where $k$, $q$ and $c$ are constants, and $s$ is the Laplace transformation variable. Because these are not tabular expressions for the inverse Laplace transformation, I started researching ways to evaluate the inverse Laplace transformations in such cases.

Currently, I am studying the residue theorem (along with other parts of complex analysis). According to that theorem, I need to find the poles of my function so I can use it. As I understand it, poles are points at which functions are not defined. This is a problem for my case because all four functions I wrote down are defined for every value of $s$. Does this mean I can not find the inverse Laplace transform for any one of them by using the residue theorem?

To summarize, I am trying to find the inverse Laplace transformation of the functions $(1)$,  $(2)$, $(3)$, and $(4)$. My questions are:

$1.$ Can I use the residue theorem to do that (at least for one of them)?

$2.$ If not, is there some other way I can find the inverse Laplace transformation of these functions?

Comment: There are no poles and so there are no residues.  You can cut the plane and integrate around the branch cuts.  I don't think that leads to anything tractable.

Comment: By tractable, do you mean there is no solution in a closed form?

Comment: Yes, no closed form.

Comment: Thank you. Since I have no other option, I will try to do this in hope that I might get an analytic expression in the end. But I'm skeptic because wolfram alpha has no solution